# Slim framework error apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, .htaccess, slim

My application is not working with Slim Framework and apache.

**Route Slim, is not working**

```
$app->group("/teste", function() {
    $this->get("/", function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {
        return $response->write("deu");
    });

    $this->get("/:nome", function(Request $request, Response $response, $args = []) {
        return $response->write("deu ".$args['nome']);
    });
});
```

**.htaccess in use** and index.php(Slim) in same location: public_html/slim/biblioteca/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Return error 500 when try access route /teste/

**Maybe need config or create httpd.conf and enable .htaccess? also AllowOverride All.**

not found this file in /etc/

Can help me?

Printscreen project list files

[image]

Comment: Check your error logs to see what causes 500.

Answer (score 0):

add below code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with,content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

OR

define root like below example :

```
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post('/example', 'examplefunction');
```

i hope it's work

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code in .htaccess file and it works

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]

</ifModule>
```